# Prove that $S=D$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

> Let nonempty subset $S \subseteq D$ where $D$ is a domain (hence $D$ is open and connected). The complement of open subset $S$ in $D$ is also open. Prove that $S=D$.

I am having some difficulty proving this statement.

I have the following, but cannot seem to show what is asked in the statement.

Assume $S \neq D$. We then know that $D \setminus S \neq \emptyset$. We are given that $D \setminus S$ is also open, which then implies that $S$ is closed.

I am stuck here, since I know that the fact that $S$ is closed does not contradict the fact that $S$ is open. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$D = S \cup (D \setminus S)$. If $D \setminus S \neq \phi$, we have found a disconnection of $D$, a contradiction since $D$ is a domain.

Answer (score 1):

Connected means that there are no non-trivial subsets which are both open and closed

Answer (score 1):

if a set is both open and closed, it is either empty or the (total) connected component containing that set (or in the union of these connected components if $A$ is in more than one connected component, which is not relevant here). So if $S$ is open and closed in $D$ then it is either empty or $S=D$. (i understand the question so, that the relevant topology is with respect to $D$).

Answer (score 1):

Assume for a contradiction that $D$ is not bounded. Then, the complement of $D$ is non-empty. But since $D$ is open, it cannot contain its boundary. Hence, the complement of $D$ contains its boundary. Similarly, any open subset of $D$ is bounded and the complement of any open subset of $D$ must contain its boundary. Therefore $D$ must be unbounded. The same argument can be used to show that both $D$ and $S$ are not bounded in every direction and that therefore $\mathbb{C}^n \subset S \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ while $\mathbb{C}^n \subset D \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, hence $S=D$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $D$ is open, the open subsets of $D$ (in the subspace topology) are precisely those open sets contained in $D$.  Then the definition of a connected space says that if $D$ is the union of two disjoint open sets, then one of them must be empty.  $S$ is non-empty, so its complement in $D$ is empty; i.e., $S=D$.